# PHP - get POST data within the include

Tags: php, post, include

So here is my situation:

I got a plugin directory that all needs the same functions. So i wrote a general.php with the common functions that is used by every plugin. Now i could let the developer of the plugin include my general.php file but this could be very annoying for him/her since its very nested so when a developer wants to include it he/she gets this: `include '../../../../../../../lib/general.php'` So what i did is let the plugin loader include the general file beforehand so that the developer wont need to access the general file every time it has a new file. Now this works and all until the developer does a form and needs to get POST data.

But i can't access the POST data inside the include, is there a way to access the POST data from the include file?

The loading kinda goes like this:

```
include '../lib/general.php';
include Plugin::GetPluginViewPath;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i can't access the POST data inside the include,

You can.

> is there a way to access the POST data from the include file?

Yes. Just access it.

As long as $_POST array is populated and not unset by some code, it is perfectly accessible everywhere.

Of course you should include PHP files, not HTTP resources, though

Comment: Sigh. I now noticed the problem, because of a database error my whole script died and thus cant access the POST variable. Thanks alot though ! Accepting the answer as to pointing me in the right direction